# TextView attribute `android:maxLength` doesn't work with `android:maxLines`

Tags: android, textview

I have a `TextView` which is defined as follows:

```
<TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLength="25"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:maxLines="5"
        android:singleLine="false" />
```

However, this results into one single line, instead of 5 lines with 3 dots at the end. `maxLength` value of 25 works, but it locks the view to being one line.

How do I achieve setting the constraint on number of characters, but at the same time, have also constraint on number of lines?

Comment: try to change android:layout_width="wrap_content" to android:layout_width="64dp" for example

Answer (score 0):

Use following code. It will help you.

```
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvTitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Sample title"
            android:maxLines="5"
            android:lines="5"
        android:textSize="20dp"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to add multiple lines in Textview

use lines property, make it unscrollable horizontally (if you want to) and set gravity from the starting of the view.

```
android:gravity="start"
android:scrollHorizontally="false"
android:lines="5"
```